# rock, paper, sciccors, lizard, spock javascript/html game

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the rock, paper, sciccors, lizard, spock game from The Big Bang Theory. I used javascript in html to make it.

```
    <button type='button' onclick='playGameame()'>Lets start!</button>
    <p id='userChoice'>You chose:</p>
    <p id='aiChoice'>Your friendly pc chose:</p>
    <p id='result'>The result is:</p>
        <script>
            function playGame(){
                var userChoice = prompt('What will be you choice of weapon?', 'rock, paper, scissors, lizard or spock'); 
                var aiChoice = Math.random();

                if (aiChoice < 0.2 ){
                    aiChoice = 'rock';
                } else if(aiChoice <= 0.4){
                    aiChoice = 'paper';
                } else if(aiChoice <= 0.6){
                    aiCoice = 'sciccors';
                } else if(aiChoice <= 0.8){
                    aiChoice = 'lizard';
                } else{
                    aiChoice = 'spock';
                }

                document.getElementById('userChoice').innerHTML = 'You chose: ' + userChoice;
                document.getElementById('aiChoice').innerHTML = 'Your friendly pc chose: ' + aiChoice;

                if (userChoice === aiChoice){
                    result = 'It\'s a tie!';
                } 
                <!-- ROCK -->
                else if (userChoice === 'rock'){
                    if (aiChoice === 'paper' || 'spock'){
                        result = 'You lose!';
                    } else {
                        result = 'You win!';
                    }
                }
                <!-- PAPER -->
                else if (userChoice === 'paper'){
                    if (aiChoice === 'lizard' || 'sciccors'){
                        result = 'You lose!';
                    } else {
                        result = 'You win!';
                    }
                }
                <!-- SCICCORS -->
                else if (userChoice === 'sciccors'){
                    if (aiChoice === 'spock' || 'rock'){
                        result = 'You lose!';
                    } else {
                        result = 'You win!';
                    }
                }
                <!-- LIZARD -->
                else if (userChoice === 'lizard'){
                    if (aiChoice === 'rock' || 'sciccors'){
                        result = 'You lose!';
                    } else {
                        result = 'You win!';
                    }
                }
                <!-- SPOCK -->
                else if (userChoice === 'spock'){
                    if (aiChoice === 'paper' || 'lizard'){
                        result = 'You lose!';
                    } else {
                        result = 'You win!';
                    }
                }

                var result = 
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The result is: ' + result;
            }
        </script>
```

The problem is that if I click on the button in my browser to call the function, the only result I get is "The result is: you lose!" or "The result is: It's a tie!". When for instance `userChoise` is rock and `aiChoise` is lizard, the result should be "you win!" but it will actually return "you lose!".

Can someone help me out?
I would appreciate it very much.

Have a nice day.

Comment: `if (aiChoice === 'paper' || 'spock')` should be `if (aiChoice === 'paper' || aiChoice === 'spock')` and so the rest.

Comment: I would also refactor everything into proper objects, a "LIZARD" object will have the "beats" property, which can be an array of other types.
Then you can simply check if "MY CHOICE" beats "HIS CHOICE". makes for a much cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I encountered another problem. Sometimes when 'aiChoise' is between 0.4 and 0.6 it will print the actual value instead of 'scissoors' and sometimes it will just print 'scissors'. Is there a logical explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using OR incorrectly. You should repeat your variable like so:
 `if (aiChoice == 'paper' || aiChoice == 'spock')` 

This problem happens because statements of the form:

```
'paper' || 'spock'
```

are evaluated to true.

Comment: Ah yes that actually sounds quite logical. Thank you c: